# what value this equal $\sin\left((2n-1)\frac{\pi}2\right)=$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

The answer is $(-1)^n$

And why is this wrong?

$$\begin{align}\sin\left[(2n-1)\frac\pi2\right]&= sin(nπ-π/2)\\
    &= \sin(n\pi) - \sin \left(\frac\pi2\right)\\
    &= 0 - 1 = -1
\end{align}$$

Comment: sin(nπ-π/2) = sin(nπ) - sin (π/2) ?? sin(a-b) = sin(a) - sin (b) ??

Comment: By yhe way, it is $(-1)^{n-1}$, not $(-1)^n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews
thank yoou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\displaystyle\sin\left(A-B\right) = \sin A-\sin B$

$$\iff2\sin\frac{A-B}2\cos\frac{A-B}2 = 2\sin\frac{A-B}2\cos\frac{A+B}2$$

$$\iff2\sin\frac{A-B}2\left(\cos\frac{A-B}2-\cos\frac{A+B}2\right)=0$$

$$\iff2\sin\frac{A-B}2\left(2\sin\frac A2\sin\frac B2\right)=0$$

Now, if $\sin x=0,x=m\pi$ where $m$ is any integer

Clearly, the supposed identity does not hold true for all $A,B$

In fact, $$\sin\left(A-B\right)=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$$

So, $$\sin\left(n\pi-\dfrac\pi2\right)=\sin(n\pi)\cos\dfrac\pi2-\cos(n\pi)\sin\dfrac\pi2=-\cos(n\pi)=-(-1)^n$$ for integer $n$

Comment: thanks, i get it, 0(0)-(-1)^n(1)

Comment: @problematic, Also shown when your equation holds.

Comment: all the trigo identities?... do you guys remember them or you  mentally 'derive' them instantly

Comment: we all know them ;-)

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin\left(n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^{n+1}$$

Comment: n+1...thanks!11